# Python; Cant import module from other directory

Tags: python, import, module

I am trying to decompose my program on `python`. I have read a lot of information and other answers about how `import` works, but still cant understand how exactly.

I want to use my module `Graph.Graph2D` for implementation in `InteractiveGraph2D`. Before importing it, I add path to this module. But it tells `NameError: name 'Graph2D' is not defined`.

Project path:

> ~/MyData/Python/Pygame/RoadSearchAlgorithm/src

Module path:

> ~/MyData/Python/Pygame/MY_MODULES/Graph

Code:

```
# ~/MyData/Python/Pygame/RoadSearchAlgorithm/src/Graph_package/InteractiveGraph2D.py

...
sys.path.append('./')
sys.path.append('/home/rayxxx/MyData/Python/MY_MODULES')
try:
    from Graph.Graph2D import Graph2D, ...
    ...
except Exception as e:
    assert (e)

class InteractiveGraph2D(Graph2D):
    ...
```

What's the problem?

I tried  to look at paths, list of imported modules. The Graph module presented in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the modules path is `~/MyData/Python/Pygame/MY_MODULES/Graph` while in the python code you added the string `'/home/rayxxx/MyData/Python/MY_MODULES'` to the os.path. Maybe the point is this

Comment: Yes, it helped, but I must add `/home/rayxxx/MyData/Python/MY_MODULES` and `/home/rayxxx/MyData/Python/MY_MODULES/Graph` so it works. Do you know why?

Comment: It's strange the second one should be enough but did not you forget a Pygame in the path between Python and MY_MODULES?

Comment: Sorry, it's mistake, there is no `Pygame` word in `Graph` path. Seems, all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the Graph module installable by adding a `setup.py` file to it's directory ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)). Then you could install it with pip and import it like any library.

Comment: Is there other way, if I dont want to make it installable?

Answer (score 0):

this is a common error, when you run a python script it looks at the dir where you are running the script so four your case when you run

```
from Graph.Graph2D import Graph2D, ...
```

From

```
~/MyData/Python/Pygame/RoadSearchAlgorithm/src
```

Python at most can import from src.

Some solution, make your module installable by adding a setup in `MY_MODULE`, then doing a pip install . in that folder, here is an example [How to setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729827/new-to-creating-a-python-package).
And maybe you need to add an **init**.py to MY_MODULES/, check here[Do I need **init**.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3-3)

Another solution is to add `MY_MODULES/` to python path, avoid this if possible but here is an example  [Add to python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114391/adding-directory-to-sys-path-pythonpath).